# Where can I get official PyTorch documentation in pdf form?

Tags: printing, pytorch, resources

I want to learn [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org) in great detail.

I have read all the docs and tutorials on the main site. I learn better from paper. When I print from website pages, I am getting very small letters. This makes the printouts difficult to read them.

The packages offer PDF documentation, but I cannot find a similar file for the main PyTorch site.

Where can I find a similar resource for official PyTorch documentation?

Comment: Not a PDF, but offline HTML just in case your internet is bad (1) https://github.com/unknownue/PyTorch.docs (2) https://devdocs.io/pytorch/

Comment: Note that this is now fairly out-of-date. ^

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an official pdf. The pytorch documentation uses [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) to generate the web version of the documentation. But sphinx can also generate PDFs.

So you could download the [git repo of pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch), install sphinx, and then generate the PDF yourself using sphinx.

The instructions to built the HTML can be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#building-the-documentation), and generating the PDF should be no different.