# Error in creating an offline PDF documentatin for PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, resources, documentation, python-sphinx

I wanted to make an offline PDF on my system for PyTorch documentation. After reading from several resources  [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220613/where-can-i-get-official-pytorch-documentation-in-pdf-form), [#2](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder), [#3](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github/cloning-a-repository)

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

cd pytorch/docs/

make latexpdf
```

First two commands are working fine. Third command leads to the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source/scripts/build_activation_images.py", line 70, in <module>
    function = torch.nn.modules.activation.__dict__[function_name]()
KeyError: 'SiLU'
```

How to overcome this error and make a PDF document of PyTorch?

---

`1.4.0` is the version of PyTorch in my system

```
print(torch.__version__)
1.4.0
```

`3.8.3` is the version of Python in my system

```
python -V
Python 3.8.3
```

Comment: Did you install the package, its requirements, and Sphinx into a Python virtual environment? That's really the best way to go to avoid harming your system Python and mixing versions of applications. If you must include `sudo` before any command, then you did not use a Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

The PyTorch version installed in your machine (1.4.0) is older than the one you cloned (most recent). Two ways to fix it:

1. Checkout to the version you have installed (if you want the doc of 1.4 version):

```py
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

# move back to the 1.4 release, which you have installed in your machine
cd pytorch
git checkout release/1.4

cd docs
make latexpdf
```

2. Upgrade to the most-recent PyTorch version (if you want the most recent doc):

```py
# upgrade PyTorch to the nightly release (change it accordingly)
python -m pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu102/torch_nightly.html

git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

cd pytorch/docs/

make latexpdf
```