# Makefile error during PyTorch documentation

Tags: pytorch, latex, documentation, python-sphinx

I [wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220613/where-can-i-get-official-pytorch-documentation-in-pdf-form) to generate a PDF documentation of PyTorch for myself and finally executed the [following commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246109/2700041) after learning

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu102/torch_nightly.html

git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

cd pytorch/docs/    

make latexpdf
```

In between I installed some dependencies related to Sphinx whenever needed.

After running the three commands. Several files including `pytorch.tex` are created in `pytorch/docs/build/latex`, but I cannot see a PDF file or can obatain a PDF from that tex file.

The last few lines from the output I got after executing the final command `make latexpdf` is as follows

```
copying TeX support files... copying TeX support files...
done
build finished with problems, 7 warnings.
make: *** [Makefile:38: latexpdf] Error 1
```

How can I overcome the error? How to get the final PDF documentation file of PyTorch?

Comment: @mzjn That is too long to post.

Comment: The pdflatex process seems to run out of memory. When I run `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode pytorch.tex`, I get this error: "pytorch.tex:97456: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]." (this is with MikTeX on Windows).

Comment: It works with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`. I get a PDF file with 1513 pages.

Comment: Can you please share the commands? @mzjn

Comment: Just run `lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode pytorch.tex` in the build/latex directory.

Comment: I also get errors and warnings (Python import errors for example) that have nothing to do with LaTeX. The `-W`  and `--keep-going` options are used, and this makes `sphinx-build` exit with exit status 1. That is probably the cause of the "make: *** [Makefile:38: latexpdf] Error 1" error.